# Discord.py cannot set up slash commands for the life of me

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Whenever I attempt to make a slash command in discord.py, the commands never work or even show up no matter how many times I sync them.

Here is a snip of the code for the slash command I wish to add
`

```
@app_commands.command(name='clearnono', description="Cleaw the numbew of nono messages you want to wemove.")
@app_commands.rename(num='quantity')
@app_commands.describe(num='How many?')
async def clear(interaction: discord.Interaction, num: int):
  await interaction.channel.purge(limit=num)
  await interaction.response.send_message(f"{num} messages were cleawed swccessfwlly.", ephemeral=True)
```

And this is the code I use to sync the commands
`

```
@bot.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.is_owner()
async def sync(
  ctx: Context, guilds: Greedy[discord.Object], spec: Optional[Literal["~", "*", "^"]] = None) -> None:
    if not guilds:
        if spec == "~":
            synced = await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)
        elif spec == "*":
            ctx.bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild=ctx.guild)
            synced = await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)
        elif spec == "^":
            ctx.bot.tree.clear_commands(guild=ctx.guild)
            await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)
            synced = []
        else:
            synced = await ctx.bot.tree.sync()

        await ctx.send(
            f"Synced {len(synced)} commands {'globally' if spec is None else 'to the current guild.'}"
        )
        return

    ret = 0
    for guild in guilds:
        try:
            await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=guild)
        except discord.HTTPException:
            pass
        else:
            ret += 1

    await ctx.send(f"Synced the tree to {ret}/{len(guilds)}.")
```

Expectation: The command is added to the bot, and I am able to use the slash command to clear messages

What actually happens: The command does not work or even show up when attempting to use it in the bot, despire the normal non-slash commands working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Did you invite your bot with the correct permissions? Bots need to be invited with the `applications.commands` scope in addition to the bot scope.
> For example, invite the bot with the following URL: https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=1234567890&scope=applications.commands+bot

- discord.py FAQ: [My bot's commands are not showing up!](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#my-bot-s-commands-are-not-showing-up)

Comment: I reinvited the bot with the link you provided, then recyned the commands, still not showing up. However, interestingly enough, slash commands do work IF I set them as a hybrid command, however, I am trying to set this as a strictly slash command.

Comment: @ThomasThorpe Wait, are you creating the slash command inside a cog? Or it's in the same file that you used to run the bot (where you're creating the bot instance)

Comment: I am not using any cogs yet as I don't really understand them, I've read over the documentation and I might start playing with them, for now, I am trying to make the slash command in my main.py where the bot is running. Could that be the problem?

Comment: If you're creating the slash command inside the `main.py` file, it is preferred to use `bot.tree.command` to register the command to the command tree. The `app_commands.command` is mainly for registering the commands in cogs. See the example [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py#L41-L44).